# How to send php variable into angularjs function (different files)

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a variable in php file reg.php. I want to send that variable into .js file in different place (app.reg.js). I tried a lot of solutions but they didn't work. I have to admit that I'm a new programmist, and this is my first own project in angularjs.
How my app exactly works :
In index.html i use routing to get to register.html (this working well).
register.html has a form app.reg.js sending it into reg.php

App.reg.js :
http://www.chopapp.com/#kpwad4zs (i'm getting ALL THE TIME "your post is not properly formatted as code -.-).
reg.php (it works fine! Just need variable $loginExist from it :

http://www.chopapp.com/#yvqivk5m
I would like to send variable from reg.php to the app.reg.js file. How to do this? I think i tried all of the solutions from here but non of them worked...

Comment: use an ajax request to call your php file

Comment: Can u send me any example? I told you i tried a lot of things but they didnt work :/

Comment: echo $loginExist; at the end of your php file. Then alert(response); in your js file

Comment: Then in alert i get only "[object response]".

Comment: try the solution i have posted and look in your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php file

```
session_start();
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$login = $request->login;
$password = $request->password;

    require_once "connect.php";

    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

    try {

        $connect = new mysqli($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

        if($connect->connect_errno!=0)

        {

            throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_errno());
        } else {


            //Does login exist?

            $result = $connect->query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE login = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($login) . "'");

            $login_count = $result->num_rows;

            if($login_count>0) {

                        $loginExist = true;

            }

            else {

                    $loginExist = false;
                    $password = $login . $password;
                    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


                    //$sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES ('$login','$password')";

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (login, password)VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($login) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($password) . "')";

                    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {

                        echo "ok!";

                    } else {

                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
                    }

            }
            $connect->close();
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Server error!';
    }
 echo json_encode(['res' => $loginExist]);
?>
```

js file

```
  app.controller('regCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $http) {
    $scope.send = function () {
        var form = {
             password: scopeToPasswordImput,
             login: scopteToLoginImput
        };
        $http({
            url:'reg1.php',
            method: "POST",
            data: form
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                //I Want to use php variable in this section
                //$window.alert("");
                console.log(response.data.res);
            } else {
                console.log("Network response was not ok.");
                window.location.href = '/';
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: Ok, now i get tons of code in log. But still i don't know how to use that variable in JS (or how to get this variable out of response).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2NavxzJ.png :| When I deep more inside there is soo much a lot of things.

Comment: try console.log(response.response);

Comment: Now I get "undefined". Ah and i stayed with "fetch". Because when I use $http it just doesn't work ([$http:badreq]).

Comment: Same like before. With console.log(response) a lot of data, with (response.response) undefined. Edit : Maybe i should use something from here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: send me a console.log of form

Comment: whats inside response.body ?

Comment: So many things i can't even copy and paste... (same like from screen). response.body : http://i.imgur.com/fDXCVF4.png

Comment: Maybe I should leave fetch and just use AJAX ?

Comment: try this js , the $http:bardeq are because url param was outside the param object :)

Comment: Ok. $http doesn't give an error. But in console i still get undefined :( + Database don't update a new user (it worked before) so i think $http still doesn't work properly.

Comment: ok we are in the good way :) sen me a console.log of your form

Comment: Oook. Now console.log(form) is sending : Object {login: "Mylogin", password: "Mypassword"}; But database still doesn't get any data, and I still get undefined from  console.log(response.data.res);

Comment: at the top of your php file put var_dump($_POST) and send me a console.log(response.data):

Comment: hm. Strange. I get syntax error here " echo json_encode('res' => $loginExist);
?>"  '=>' is the problem.

Comment: i forget the square brackets :) this is the problem is it good now ?

Comment: Now i get "undefined index: login" and "Undefined index: password". To database only password is being added. Login is empty.

Comment: We are close, send me the var dump of $_POST

Comment: Strange... I get : array(0) {
}   And, when i json_encode it says its null.

Comment: It just doesn't get my login. I don't know why. Maybe  $login = $_POST['login']; should look different? About vardump i did "$something = var_dump($_POST);" and then echo json_encode(['res2' => $something]); . In console.log(response.data) i "get res2 = null"

Comment: Exactly. It's still something wrong with $http function in JS file.

Comment: this is because $http sending json :) i have the solution i ll edit my response

Comment: It works <3 Thanks man. Now last question. In console.log(response.data) i get {"res":"false"}. What i need to do to create var in js file that have "false" or "true" from this response? EDIT : Nvm just response.data.res . Man I love you! #notgay

Comment: var loginExist = response.data.res :)